# Extending SocketChannel in JRE 1.7.4+

Tags: java, socketchannel

I just tried extending `SocketChannel` but it seems that `SocketChannel` has some new API methods available starting from JRE 1.7.4 ([`SocketChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html)).  The problem is if I implement those methods, my JAR would throw the following error whenever I'm using Java 1.6

```
Exception in thread "Thread-24" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/channels/NetworkChannel
```

Now I figured out why there is an error related to `java/nio/channels/NetworkChannel`, it appears that `SocketChannel` implements interface `NetworkChannel` starting on JRE 1.7

Now, when I'm using JRE 1.7.4+, some runtime error occurs.  Actually the weird thing is even if I have those new API methods implemented then I'm getting runtime error when I call the `unwrap` method:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-27" java.lang.RuntimeException: Delegated task threw Exception/Error
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at CustomSocketChannel.unwrap(CustomSocketChannel.java:565)
```

On that line I just call the `sslEngine.unwrap` method.  So in short when I have the new API methods implemented, it only works with JRE 1.7.0 to 1.7.3

How can I make my JAR compatible with JRE 1.6 and 1.7 while also extending the `SocketChannel` class?

Comment: Do you have some stacktrace? Usually it should be no problem to have a "newer" JRE than Development-JDK.

Comment: If I compile JAR in JRE 1.6 and then run it in JRE 1.7 without implementing new methods I get the following error

Exception in thread "Thread-27" java.lang.RuntimeException: Delegated task threw Exception/Error
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
 at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you add some code? This doesn't make any sense to me, really.

Comment: @Code.Blodded - is that the entire stack trace?

Comment: I don't reference any NetworkChannel at all here is a sample implementation of the method marked as an @Override

   
     public SocketChannel shutdownOutput() throws IOException {
            return socketChannel.shutdownOutput();
     }

Comment: Can you implement the new methods for 1,7 and compile the class using 1.6?

Comment: @jtahlborn I can compile on 1.6 even with the 1.7 methods added although I still get same runtime error, actually this only seems to work when I'm using JRE 1.7.0 to 1.7.3, if I'm using 1.7.4 above then I have the runtime error problem

Comment: please add the full details to your question as it's getting a little confusing trying to follow it all in comments.

Comment: @jtahlborn added details in question

Comment: From the answer, it looks like the issue was in the implementation of `getAcceptedIssuers`, which wasn't even mentioned in the actual question.  Voting to close as missing the required details to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems like I have pinpointed the issue about the runtime error on JRE 1.7.4+.  It appears that it is not really the unwrapping error but rather the certificate error.  Again I'm also getting the following error whenever I'm getting that runtime error when I call `SSLEngine.unwrap`:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-24" java.lang.RuntimeException: Delegated task threw Exception/Error
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    .....
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at ....RTMPSTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers(....)
```

Silly me I should have noticed that "Caused by" phrase, since I have this code below, so it seems that starting from JRE 1.7.4.  If I throw an exception inside `getAcceptedIssuers()` then I'll have that problem, so I just ended up not throwing an exception but returning `null` instead.

I'm not sure if that 1.7.4+ problem is related to this fix ([JDK-7142172](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7142172)), but it really seems to be.

```java
public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
{
    return null;
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Comment: It isn't valid to return null from that method. Check the Javadoc. At a minimum you should return an empty array, but if this is the infamous trust-anybody TrustManager you should throw it away and get your certificates working. It is radically insecure and not to be incorporated into new code.